# Cannot import com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsQueueConnectionFactory with Gradle

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, tibco, tibco-ems, tibco-business-works

so I've been working on migrating a Maven project over onto a Gradle one. While doing so, I can across a class called `TibjmsQueueConnectionFactory` that I've been trying to figure out how trying to import. I've found most of my other imports on [MVNRepository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.tibco/tibjms/4.4.3) however, none of the ones I try for this one seem to work.

This is basically all I'm trying to do:

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.tibco/tibjms
    implementation group: 'com.tibco', name: 'tibjms', version: '1.0'
```

I did see somewhere that Tibco may not exist at that location at all, and maybe I'll have to download a jar file, but I'm not sure if this is the case or not. Has anyone else had this issue before? How did you resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

A possible maven project pom dependency solution is available in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62897427/15405413).
You can get `tibjms-4.1` from pom uploaded in [openmindonline](http://repository.openmindonline.it/tibco-ems/tibjms/4.1/tibjms-4.1.pom) repo which has `TibjmsQueueConnectionFactory`. We are not able to access other version from [icm](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.tibco/tibjms?repo=icm).

Add openmindonline repo information in your repositories block in your `build.gradle`

```
repositories {
    // You can declare any Maven/Ivy/file repository here.
    maven {
        url "http://repository.openmindonline.it/"
    }
}
```

Then add `implementation 'tibco-ems:tibjms:version:4.1'` in `dependencies` block.

If you have jar file available locally, you can follow solutions available in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20700053/how-to-add-local-jar-file-dependency-to-build-gradle-file).